# Is there an efficient way to return by value for self assignment?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, return-value

The usual cpp advice for output parameters is: "avoid passing output parameters by modifiable reference, return by value instead".  Now if we have a case where we want to modify an object itself, e.g.

```
string s = "whatever";
//maybe in a loop
s = modify(s);
```

Then it looks like a function `string modify (string)` is always outperformed by a function like `modifyInPlace(string &)`.  Is there any way around this problem? Is there any fundamental reason why this can never be solved? I think the semantics of take by value, return by value are safer and clearer.

Example comparison measurement:
http://quick-bench.com/-XZqOZw-X739tlcOI8vau8DU24w

Comment: I don't know where you got that advice.  All the operator overloaded methods return references (granted they are to themselves).  Just like the overloaded operators you would typically make the call on the object itself (i.e. `s.modify(string&)`)  Then your `s` object would be modified.  But then again the `string` class is not yours.

Comment: Advice is for `std::string generate_password();` versus `void generate_password(string&);`. Here it is an input and output parameter.

Comment: You  misplace your move BTW [Demo](http://quick-bench.com/CoKdZyjVtuyIMP09RTLYe5qftCQ). Your move is useless are compiler you do it for you in return statement.

Comment: @Jarod  I did not, the compiler cannot do it for me in the return statement when returning named function parameters (NRVO rules in standard)

Comment: @jiveturkey an example of the advice:
https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-out

Comment: I DEFINITELY don't want to start a flame war but his reasoning is that it is self-documenting.  I believe that's VERY poor reasoning to prefer documenting vs. performance.  I am a fan of readability so in my projects I define an empty #define `#define OUT ` then I am able to define a method such as `void example(const Me& inMe, OUT Me& outMe)`

Comment: NRVO doesn't apply to parameter, but [return statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Notes) does move for parameter (if applicable and it is in your case).

Comment: Even your benchmark shows no timing difference from both version. (mine shows, so impact of move is visible).

Comment: @AKludges: In same link, you have [F.17: For "in-out" parameters, pass by reference to non-const](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-inout). and also [exception: in/out parameters](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#exception-11).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way around this problem?

You have to make a choice. Either

- create a modified copy, which may be expensive for some types, or
- Modify in place, which does not conform to the preference that you describe, but may be faster for some types.

You need to consider which is more important for your program.

That said, the overhead of the modified copy is usually not significant if you create it by move:

```
s = modify(std::move(s));
```

Here is a modified version of your benchmark: http://quick-bench.com/X_ONMO_yiAqbkkcbvsiC_Xpk5Sw

---

The "no reference output parameters" rule of thumb works well when you create a new value that is not based on an existing value of the same type. In such case there is typically no in-place alternative available.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying by reference will almost always be faster than modifying by value, unless your values are very small in size (e.g. an `int`). This is because, when you modify by value, you have to create a copy of the value in memory to pass to the function, while references don't have to do that.